# how to get all the repos which have a security vulnerability issue open on github(array of repos are there)

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I'm having around 10 repos, in which i need to get is there any open security vulnerability issues open in any of them if yes, then i need to get the url for the issue, the query params mentioned in the documentation is quite confusing, may be i'm new to it

what i had tried till now. but in this i'm not able to pass security vulnerability tag,any help would be much appriciated, thanks

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: token <my-token>" https://github.com/api/v3/search/issues?q={ORG}/{repo-name}+type:issue+state:open
```

it gives me the repo with issues open also how can i pass multiple repos and also how can i add security-vulnerability as the tag for the issues, thanks